# Office Automation hangs with Windows 7 and Office 2007

Tags: excel, multithreading, delphi, automation

I have a Delphi XE8 program where I use Office Automation to build an Excel file. The building takes a few seconds so I have put this work into a background thread so that my program would remain responsive and I can process a cancel request.

I had set it up this way:

```
TTask.Run(
  procedure
  var
    oXL, oSheet, o2Sheet, oRng, VArray : Variant;
  begin
    oXL := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    oXL.Visible := False;
    oXL.DisplayAlerts := false;

    ... (all the processing to build the Excel file)

    oXL.Application.Workbooks[1].SaveAs(ExcelFilename, 51 { = xlWorkbookDefault } );
    oXL.Workbooks.Close;
    oXL.Application.Quit;
    oXL := Unassigned;
  end
);
```

This code worked absolutely fine, just the way I wanted it to. It created the Excel workbook as a background task, returned from the task back to the main thread properly when done, and the application remained responsive.

I thought everything was great. It worked on my Windows 10 computer with Office 2016. I had several users who ran it successfully on their computers as well.

But I had a report from one user where the program hung while in the thread. I was able to do some tests. When the code was not run in a thread on his machine, it worked fine (except of course the application no longer remained responsive and I couldn't process the cancel request).

The only thing different about the user's machine that I could tell is that they were running Windows 7 and Office 2007.

I am not 100% certain that Office Automation is threadsafe. Can I put it all into a thread, with the understanding that some of the automation commands (which ones?) may need synchronizing? If it is not threadsafe, how else might I keep my application responsive while the Excel file is being generated?

Could it be that a difference between Office Automation on Windows 7 versus Windows 10 or Office 2007 versus Office 2016 is causing the Task to fail in the older versions? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Surely the real code doesn't say 51. You have to stop using magic constants if it does and define the appropriate constants.

Comment: @DavidHefferman - I had to search the web to find what code to use (xlWorkbookDefault) and what its value was because office automation constants are not included in the Delphi XE8 Pro package.

Comment: So define them in your code.

Comment: Office automation constants are defined in the Delphi import units (see Excel2010.pas, in your $(BDSDIR)\OCX\Servers folder). It's defined as `xlWorkbookDefault = $00000033;`, which is how it should be defined in your code. For future reference, you can import the Excel type library using Components->Import Component, and the Delphi unit it creates will contain all of the definitions you need, and you can use it as a reference rather than searching the web.

Comment: It's also important to note, although i assume you're not doing it here, you cannot automate Office applications outside of a logged in user (e.g. cannot do it from a service, or from a scheduled task that isn't running as the currently logged in user). Aside from user profiles not being loaded, the biggest issue is that sometimes Office apps will show a modal dialog - with no way for anyone to see or click it. This would cause the automated Office application to appear to hang.

Comment: @IanBoyd - Thanks. No. User is logged in.

Comment: @KenWhite - Yes. And the OCX directory source is not supplied with the Professional version of Delphi XE8.

Comment: Yes, it is, and has been since Delphi 2 or 3. That's exactly where I located the file; I have never owned a SKU other than Pro since it was introduced. And any version of Delphi can import the Excel type library to get the definitions. Did you opt out of installing the Office wrappers during installation? That's the only way I can think of that it wouldn't be there.

Comment: @KenWhite Whoops. You're right.  I was looking in the Source directories. Thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed. The import unit is nothing more than the output of the type library importer. It seems you aren't familiar with COM. Worth learning more.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes, this is my first experience with Office Automation, and with threading for that matter. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Does the ExcelFilename exists when you try to save it? if yes maybe Excel is prompting you and you cant see the dialog...

Comment: @kobik - No. I put the date and time (to the second) into the file name. I did run into that sort of problem for another dialog and I got around it by adding oXL.DisplayAlerts := false;

Answer (score 5):

The obvious flaw is that you did not initialize COM in the thread. Call `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx`.

There is certainly no problem with automating Excel from a background thread. What you are attempting is possible. It is conceivable that there are bugs in the code you did not show but the missing COM initialization is the only fault that can be seen in the code in the question.

Of course COM initialization is not easy when you don't control the life of the thread. The threading library creates the thread and you don't know what has been running in that thread already. If I were you I would create a thread explicitly and avoid the task based approach of the threading library.

Comment: The thread is only running the building of the Excel file. It is not due to bugs in my code because putting in just the CreateOleObject statement and Close/Quit statements and leaving everything else out has the same result. What may (or may not) be significant that I failed to note in my question is If I put the CreateOleObject and Close/Quit object into a Synchronize statement, then it works on my user's machine. Of course, that simply gets it to run in the main thread again.

Comment: It will surely be a bug in your code. Always doubt your own code above all else. The big bug that is visible is, as I said, that you did not initialize COM. In a VCL app COM is initialized on the main thread.

Comment: Technically its not a bug *in* my code. It's a bug because I left something out of my code. :-)

Comment: Omission of essential code is a mistake just as is inclusion of erroneous code.

Comment: I added the CoInitializeEx(nil, coInit); statement to my task and updated my question above to show it. The code still works fine on my machine and several other user machines. I tested it on my user's machine who has Windows 7 and Office 2007, and the Office Automation still hangs. So my problem remains the same and unsolved.

Comment: It's not fair to ask a new question in an edit. I reverted. I guess your next step is to ask a new question with a clear [mcve]. At least then we won't have to guess what all the missing code is.

Comment: David: I never asked a new question. Your answer was that I was missing the CoInitializeEx line. I added it and it did not fix my problem, so I still have the same the question and it is unchanged. If you want, I could include the 100 or so lines where all I'm doing is adding the data and setting column widths and formats. But that part works.

Comment: Nope. Different question. It's not fair to change it completely after than answer that finds all the defects with the question as asked. Time to make a [mcve] and ask a new question. Try with a thread rather than a task too. Could easily be some whacky issue with threading library.

Comment: Okay. I'll see if a thread works. If so, I'll accept your answer. If not, I may ask another question.

Comment: Remember that this is not a site for personal one to one debugging sessions. It is simple Q&A and it should be of use to future visitors. It is just not fair to expect us to debug a never ending moving target. You asked. I answered what you asked. To move on you need to create a [mcve]. You probably will find that will be enough for you to solve it. Debugging is a hugely important skill. It will be immensely useful for you to hone your debugging skills.